# Overheating while running Linux in Laptop

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kernel, cpu, hardware

I've been running into issues while running Linux Mint MATE 19 64-bit in my laptop (Toshiba L750). It's installed in a SSD drive and there are 16GB of RAM installed.

I purchased a SSD to move to Linux, (Win7 was installed in my previous mechanical drive), but I'm feeling very disapointed to see the results. If the desktop is opened with no applications running everything seems fine, but when I open a simple editor, Libre Office, firefox, etc. the fan runs at a maximum Speed.

After searching on internet this issue, I see that was suggested to use "sensors" to monitor temperature: in Win 7 the temperature of both Cores (Core i5-2450) is around 39-41 ºC, reaching 45ºC while playing a Youtube video in Firefox (fan remains silent), while in Linux the base temperature is around 49-52 ºC reaching 65ºC while playing a video in Firefox.

I found really strange that there appear only 2  states in the governor: "Performance" and "Powersave", and this last one is the one used, but does not seem to work fine, since it should be very conservative while stepping up the processor frequency, but it is almost instantaneous (sometimes even moving the mouse or minimizing a program cause the processor to run at a maximum speed).

In Windows the base speed seems to be around 780MHz, reaching 1400MHz while the video is being played while in Linux the base speed is around 1200MHz reaching 2400MHz while playing the video.

In case this was caused by Linux Mint, I installed Lubuntu 18.04 with the very same results.

I also read somewhere in stackexchange that this could be caused by the graphics card, so I tried to use both nvidia and xorg drivers, with the very same results, so I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Is Linux created for Desktop computers only?

Could anyone please point in the right direction?

Note: I'm not providing reference links because I tried dozens of different solutions.

**EDIT:**
As requested by @Sparhawk, here I attach a couple of screenshots of htop:
[image]
The picture above belongs to an "idle" state.

[image]
The picture above is the state of the system while moving the mouse. I don't know whether this is normal or not but seems to be an issue with the graphics?

Comment: Welcome! Please add links to the references you used to come up with your conclusions.

Comment: Hi, please, do not remove information like the hardware (SSD), since sometimes firmware can cause issues. I beg you not to remove my questions, because maybe they are not important for you but they are for me. IMHO there is plenty enough information in the post about the solutions applied, but in case you need "specific" information on anything, please ask for it. This account is new, but I'm not new to the community, so please, don't treat me like that.

Comment: I've been running Linux for several years on multiple laptops, which have been working fine. It could be a process that is running wild. Could you please install some kind of process analyser, e.g. `htop` and look at how much CPU is being used overall, and whether the top hits are using much CPU?

Comment: @Sparhawk, thanks for your time. I've just edited the post to include the ouput of htop. Do you think there is an issue with the graphics?

Comment: Yes, that seems pretty high just for moving the mouse around. Is it 100% replicable? Does it drop back similar to the first screenshot when you stop? Also, I'm not too familiar with Compton, but did you install that manually, or by default?

Comment: I have a NVIDIA 520M graphics card and I've seen some complaints of Linux not managing properly Optimus. Anyway those posts are old, but I'm guessing whether is is the source of the issue

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes, it is 100% replicable. I think compton is installed by default or at least I've not installed it voluntarily

Comment: I've just been notified with a new update of the nvidia drivers, and there is an improvement in the temperature and consequently the fan speed. I've also disabled compton, but the temperature still remains higher than in windows, and I think this is caused by the governor, since while I was monitoring the speed, the processor seems to step up very fast, while it should be slower. Is there any way to control this?

Comment: Ah, Optimus… Linux manages it okay, apart from being slightly clunky to start. By default, it shouldn't be running; you need to manually invoke it. So it shouldn't affect battery/CPU. I think it's possible to tweak the governor, but if there's a high load then the CPU will push harder no matter what. There's clearly a high load, so I'd look to troubleshoot that first, and see if it fixes things. I presume that Compton isn't meant to run so hard, but as above I have no experience. Hopefully someone else can step in. Also, consider posting on a Mint board; you might get more relevant users.